# How to apply the class to a tag from the controller (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class

I have a call to the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/table", :locals => {:@number => "10 этаж", :@apartmentq => @apartment10, :apartment => @apartment, :stalytd =>@stalytd} %>
```

Partial:

```
<% @apartmentq.each do |apartment| %>
      <td  onclick="location.href='<%= edit_apart_path(apartment) %>' "><table id="tabletd" class="<%= @stalytd %>">.......
```

And part controller:

```
 def statusapart
        @fio=apartment.f_buyer
        @ifo=apartment.i_buyer
        if (@fio != nil && @ifo != "")
            @stalytd=redcolor
        else
            @stalytd=greencolor
       end 
    end
```

This does not work.
How can I change the class of the tag to apply a different style depending on the value f_buyer and i_buyer in object apartment transmittable in partial?

Answer (score 0):

if you pass params to your partial you access the variable on the left side

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/table", :locals => { stalytd1: @stalytd2} %>
```

so in your partial you'll acees the passed value as stalytd1. 
atm you do it exactly the other way around, you pass the instance variable, but you also access the instance variable inside the partial.
you schould just remove the @